# Vue UI not launching on new project

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I just created a new project. It's the second one I started. I installed vue cli globally with npm. Furthermore, I created the project with vue create, but otherwise I haven't changed a thing yet. When I run `vue ui` it does open a new tab in my browser but it doesn't load. After a few seconds this will be outputted in my terminal

```
  Starting GUI...
  Ready on http://localhost:8001
node:events:368
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/XXXX/Projects/XXXXXXX/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/locales'
    at Object.readdirSync (node:fs:1390:3)
    at exports.readdir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/sync/fs.js:18:20)
    at Object.safeCall [as safe] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/call.js:24:8)
    at DirectoryReader.readNextDirectory (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/directory-reader.js:78:10)
    at Readable.DirectoryReader.stream._read (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/directory-reader.js:57:18)
    at Readable.read (node:internal/streams/readable:496:27)
    at readdirSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/sync/index.js:27:21)
    at Function.readdirSyncStat (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/index.js:34:10)
    at ReaderSync.dynamicApi (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fast-glob/out/providers/reader-sync.js:64:24)
    at ReaderSync.api (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fast-glob/out/providers/reader-sync.js:56:25)
Emitted 'error' event on Readable instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:164:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'scandir',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/Users/XXXX/Projects/XXXXXX/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/locales'
}
```

I checked if I could add some kind of locales package to my local yarn dependencies, but that didn't do the trick. What am I missing?

EDIT:

I'm at a loss... I deleted the project. Opened the UI again. Created a new project through the UI. It installed all the packages for me, and ended with the same error message.

Comment: Can you say what is your node version? Although it seems absurd, did you do `npm install` before running the project?

Comment: @CristianPoley npm --version returns 8.1.3, Node.js is v17.0.1

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
The cause of the problem is NodeJS version 17.
Don't use NodeJS v17, use NodeJS v16 (this is LTS) version instead.
After running with v16, there was no problem creating and running the project via Vue UI.